# Update random row according to condition

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a database with rows where a column is null. I want to update random rows with a new value on this column however I'm having trouble writing the SQL for this.

```
UPDATE TOP 1 [dbo].Invoice SET 
document_id = @guid
WHERE document_id IS NULL
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

What I want to do here is update the document_id with a new guid on 1 random row. (the actual guid is not seen above)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a CTE here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 document_id
    FROM [dbo].Invoice
    WHERE document_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)

UPDATE cte
SET document_id = @guid;
```